# Why is xargs used in this statement

Tags: bash, xargs

I'm interacting with an AWS CLI command called [`configure`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/configure/set.html) with the following syntax:

```
aws configure set varname value
```

I've come across the following script:

```
aws configure set environment $(echo $ENV | xargs)
```

I know that this is setting the `environment` `varname` to the output of `$ENV`.

Why is the `echo` commanding piping its output to `xargs`? I've read the man page but I do not understand what it's doing.

Comment: @JasonStrimpel : What is the content of `ENV`?

Comment: `$ENV` is a string like `staging`

Comment: @anubhava yes likely but this is not my code

Comment: xargs is not needed here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xargs as you know from man `construct argument list(s) and execute utility`

here it will format the output of echo $ENV to be a list of arguments instead of rows to demonstrate this try these commands on your Linux machine

```
env | xargs
```

the output will be formatted like this

```
rvm_script_name= rvm_sdk= rvm_silent_flag= rvm_sticky_flag= rvm_system_flag= rvm_use_flag= rvm_user_flag= rvm_ruby_string=ruby-2.3.0 _=/usr/bin/env
```

then try

```
env
```

the output will be like this

```
rvm_system_flag=
rvm_use_flag=
rvm_user_flag=
rvm_ruby_string=ruby-2.3.0
_=/usr/bin/env
```

so it prepares the output of the command `echo $ENV` to be valid as a list of arguments by removing the new lines

Comment: wrong: it works without xargs too, because LF is a valid word separator too. test it with `echo $( printf "a\nb\nc\n" | xargs)` and `echo $( printf "a\nb\nc\n" )`

Comment: Probably for this specific case, it works but it's one of the uses of xargs anyway and maybe the one who wrote the command is used to use xargs to such cases